# does async/await method run in the same thread as caller?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have read that async/await methods runs in the same thread as caller and I saw it in a WPF application but while testing a code in console application I see it is running in a different thread than caller.
Have I missed something?
[image]

Comment: There is no thread: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Have I missed something?

Sort of.  `await` doesn't know anything about *threads*.  It causes the code after the `await` keyword (by default) to run in the same `SynchronizationContext` as the caller, if it exists.

In the case of a WPF Application, the current `SynchronizationContext` is setup to marshal the call back to the UI thread, which means it will end up on the UI thread.  (The same is true in Windows Forms).  In a Console Application, there is no `SynchronizationContext`, so it can't post back onto that context, which means you'll end up on a ThreadPool thread.

If you were to install a custom `SynchronizationContext` into `SynchronizationContext.Current`, the call would post there.  This is not common in Console Applications, however, as it typically requires something like a "message loop" to exist to work properly.