# Await and different thread id for the same code

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a problem understanding why the rest of the function after using async is done in different threads for the same code. Take an example - in CODE 1 the rest of the **RunClick** function is executed in thread 3, which is logical, because the DoAsyncWork function was executed in it.

In the case of CODE 2, the rest of the **btnCallMethod_Click** function is still executed in thread 1., although the function DoWorkAsync was done in thread 3.

The only difference is that `btnCallMethod_Click`
is called from Windows Forms - it handles Click event for a standard button.

What does it depend on ? Does Windows Forms trigger events in any special way that the thread does not change?

```
//CODE 1:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp61
{

    class Test
    {
        public event EventHandler Click;
        public string TestString { get; set; }
        internal void DoClick()
        {
            Click?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        public async void RunClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before async call " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); // Thread id=1
            (sender as Test).TestString = await DoAsyncWork(1);
            Console.WriteLine("After async call " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); //Thread id=3 OK
        }

        private Task<string> DoAsyncWork(int step)
        {
            return Task.Run(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine($"DoAsyncWork() " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); //Thread id=3
                return "555";
            });
        }
    }

    class Program
    {     
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test x = new Test();
            x.Click += x.RunClick;
            x.DoClick();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CODE 2:
private async void btnCallMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("step 1-" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); //Thread id=1
            this.Text = await DoWorkAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("step 2-" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); //Thread id=1 Still 1 !!! Why ? Should  be 3
        }

        private async Task<string> DoWorkAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("step 99-" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); // Thread id =3
                return "Done with work!";
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you asking why `await` continues in same thread in UI, but in different thread if it's not UI? You can find some insights in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21390186/1997232).

Comment: It's never good to use Thread.Sleep() in async code - try replacing this with await Task.Delay() and remove the unnecessary Task.Run() from your DoWorkAsync(), then see if you still get the same results.

Comment: Yes, the question is: why await continues in the same thread if method is called from UI, and why not if it's called from my private class (event).

Comment: Take a look at: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/  it's well explained

Comment: I recommend reading my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be 3 in the `code 2`. It's all about `synchronization context`.

There is no `synchronization context` in console application, so task continuations are executed on thread pool in `code 1`.

`WPF` and `WinForms` applications have `synchronization context` to route execution back to `UI` thread to modify controls for instance.

Try this `this.Text = await DoWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` in the 2nd example and your code won't be returned to thread `1`.

Also check my answer here [Is ConfigureAwait(false) required on all levels of the async chain when no real I/O call is involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054770/is-configureawaitfalse-required-on-all-levels-of-the-async-chain-when-no-real/57055807#57055807)

[What Is SynchronizationContext](http://hamidmosalla.com/2018/06/24/what-is-synchronizationcontext/)